# CSS checkbox highlight image with border when checked

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a wp site with contact forms 7 plugin..

I have set up the form with some checkboxes that have images for the content.. here is the html

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5L6waw1d/#&togetherjs=7ePbSVaGoV)

I am trying to make a border around the image when a checkbox is selected...

```
<div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f299-p295-o1" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
  <div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
  <form action="/apply-for-trial/#wpcf7-f299-p295-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="trials-option">
      <label>
        <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap trials-list">
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox wpcf7-validates-as-required"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first last">
    <input type="checkbox" name="trials-list[]" value="trial 1">&nbsp;
    <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">trial 1</span>
        </span>
        </span>
        </span>
        <img src="http://clinics.dsgthemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/trial-16.png">
        <br>
      </label>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

again, trying to make the img inside label have a border when selected..
I have added a class that makes the checkbox bigger, just for me to verify I am selecting the check box.. the problem is that I am not selecting the img, and I cannot figure out a way to do it.

```
#wpcf7-f299-p295-o1 > form > div > label > input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}

#wpcf7-f299-p295-o1 > form > div > label > input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ img {
  border: 3px solid #888;
}
```

tried this way: (but it isn't immediately after the check box..)

```
#wpcf7-f299-p295-o1 > form > div > label > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + img {
  border: 3px solid #888;
}
```

and many others.. I can't seem to get it, any help?

Comment: Your current DOM structure does not allow for the image to be selected from the checkbox. You would have to traverse up to the parent and select the parent span's sibling, which is the image, but traversing up the DOM in CSS is not possible. You can do it with javascript, or you can change the DOM to put your image inside the same span as the checkbox

Comment: thanks, so move the image around or restructure the way it is setup..

Comment: Yeah, you can only select siblings and children with CSS. The easiest solution would be to move either the checkbox or the image so that they are next to each other in the DOM, but if that's not possible, let me know and we can come up with a javascript solution

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5L6waw1d/1/ Seems to do what you want it to

Comment: yes, that does seem to be working, but it looks like I don't have that kind of control over this form... it am using a plugin where I have to use shortcodes to implement the checkbox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restructure the DOM like so:

## HTML

```
<form action="/apply-for-trial/#wpcf7-f299-p295-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="trials-option">
      <label>
        <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap trials-list">
           <span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox wpcf7-validates-as-required">
             <span class="wpcf7-list-item first last">
                <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">trial 1</span>
                <input type="checkbox" name="trials-list[]" value="trial 1">&nbsp;<img src="http://clinics.dsgthemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/trial-16.png">
             </span>
           </span>
        </span>
      </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

And then use this selector in your CSS

## CSS

```
.trials-option input[type="checkbox"]:checked + img {
  border: 3px solid #888;
}
```

## Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/5L6waw1d/2/

Comment: Thanks that works!!! Glad I wasn't going crazy and it was structure (which is what I thought, but needed a second set of eyes)